# Is it possible to check if done button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have notification on movie player:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
            selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
              object:nil];
```

And it's handler:

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification 
{    
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

  // Remove observer
 [[NSNotificationCenter  defaultCenter] 
  removeObserver:self
  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
  object:nil];

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Here in this handler method I want to check if the done button is sender. Because I have two senders to this method. How ti check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per docs: `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` userInfo dictionary must contain NSNUmber for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey` key indicating the reason playback has finished. Its possible values:

```
enum {
   MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded,
   MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError,
   MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to assign tag to your buttons before the action and then check the value of the sender tag.

Just add these lines of code:

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
      NSInteger anyInteger = [sender tag];
      //Now check the value of the anyInteger and write the code accordingly.
     //switch case or if condition whatever you want.
}
```

That's it.

Comment: Dear friend First assign the value of tag to your buttons in code or your nib file.Ex     btnFirst.tag = 1.Once you do this you can access the value of the tag of the sender button.

Answer (score 0):

Add tag with the button and put condition according to the tag.

Or check by

```
if([sender isEqual:btn1])
{

}
else 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I stumbled upon it while looking for a solution, and the accepted solution doesn't show the final code.
Here is what you have to do:

```
- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
```

{
    NSLog(@"moviePlayBackDidFinish");

```
// Remove observer
```

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                            name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                            object:nil];

```
NSInteger movieFinishReason=  [[[notification userInfo]objectForKey:
                               MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] intValue];


if(movieFinishReason == 2 || movieFinishReason == 1 || movieFinishReason == 0){
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
/*
 MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded  = 0,//played movie sucessfuly.
 MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError = 1, //error in playing movie
 MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited = 2;  //user quitting the application / user pressed done button
 */
```

}